# Unable to extract data from JSON in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, json-extract

I have a JSON data as below

```
    [
  "{\"category\":\"a\"}",
  "{\"category\":\"b\"}",
  "{\"category\":\"c\"}",
  "{\"category\":\"d\"}",
  "{\"category\":\"e\"}",
  "{\"category\":\"f\"}",
  "{\"category\":\"g\"}",
  "{\"category\":\"h\"}",
  "{\"category\":\"i\"}",
  "{\"category\":\"j\"}",
  "{\"category\":\"k\"}",
  "{\"category\":\"l\"}",
  "{\"category\":\"m\"}",
  "{\"category\":\"n\"}",
  "{\"category\":\"o\"}",
  "{\"category\":\"p\"}",
  "{\"category\":\"q\"}"
]
```

I am using the below query by the result I am getting is *NULL*

```
SELECT DISTINCT T_ID,
                ITC,
                JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(REPLACE(ITC,'\\',''), 'category') AS cat,
                prop.VALUE::string AS cat1
FROM MDCD.M.T01 a,
     LATERAL FLATTEN(input => a.ITC, outer => true) prop
```

Both the *cat* and *cat1* are resulting as *NULL*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why cat1 is Null but the JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT returns null because this is an array. You would need to specify an array index for it to extract the JSON at that slot of the array.

EDITED: to include index column from flatten to specify the array index for JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.

```sql
create or replace temporary table t0 (cat variant) as
select parse_json(column1) from values
('[{"category":"a"},  {"category":"b"},  {"category":"c"},  {"category":"d"},  {"category":"e"},  {"category":"f"},  {"category":"g"},  {"category":"h"},  {"category":"i"},  {"category":"j"},  {"category":"k"},  {"category":"l"},  {"category":"m"},  {"category":"n"},  {"category":"o"},  {"category":"p"},  {"category":"q"}]');

select 
json_extract_path_text(cat[index], 'category') as cat,
prop.value::string as cat1
from t0,
lateral flatten(input => t0.cat, outer => true) prop;
```

| CAT | CAT1 |
| --- | --- |
| a | {"category":"a"} |
| b | {"category":"b"} |
| c | {"category":"c"} |
| d | {"category":"d"} |
| e | {"category":"e"} |
| f | {"category":"f"} |
| g | {"category":"g"} |
| h | {"category":"h"} |
| i | {"category":"i"} |
| j | {"category":"j"} |
| k | {"category":"k"} |
| l | {"category":"l"} |
| m | {"category":"m"} |
| n | {"category":"n"} |
| o | {"category":"o"} |
| p | {"category":"p"} |
| q | {"category":"q"} |

Comment: Thanks Dave. your query returns only 1 record. However I am expecting the number of records to be same as the no. of items in the underlying JSON.

Comment: The output above is from the query. One line per category a-q using prop.value::string as cat1 from the lateral flatten. The JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT does not return the different categories as I only  specified the first array element to demonstrate that it is an array.

Comment: The query above is returning 17 rows. It is updated to use the index column from the lateral flatten to select from the array.

Comment: Cool Dave. This works exactly as my expectation.